# Ideas for small no low-maintenance plantation

Tags: plant-recommendations

I am from eastern Europe and looking for ideas on how to domesticate some small acreage (about 0.75 hectare). I don't want to sell this area and maybe there are some ways (which won't require lot of work, let's say no more than some maintenance, few times per year) to create some revenue out of it in the future. Maybe there are some species of conifer which meet these requirements? Are there are any interesting books / websites that provide an overview of the possibilities (with regard to possible income) for beginners?

Comment: Where is the land located, what is the soil, how many hours, money are you willing to put in yearly? This is a very broad question

Comment: You could grow your own food with permaculture design techniques.

Comment: Welcome to Gardening SE! This question is skirting the borders of what is on topic here. First, we don’t accept questions about large-scale agriculture and business topics. So creating revenue can’t be the focus of your question (But may perhaps be a side effect). Which leads us to the second issue: without more details, this is really too broad. Please take the [tour] and browse through our [help], especially [ask], then [edit] your post to clarify, thanks. What may help is a better description of the plot of land, climate, previous use... If you have questions about this, we’re here to help.

Comment: Putting this on hold until further clarification.